# How do I make the focus point indicators stay long enough to select on the Canon 60D?

Tags: canon, autofocus, camera-settings, focus-point-selection, viewfinder-indicators

I have just switched from the Canon 500D to a 60D. Most of my work is property based, and this is therefore 90% internal flash shots where I often wish to pick out a particular spot for best focus.

On the 500D I could hit the AF point selection button (top RH) which would show all 9 alternatives. I would then use the main dial to toggle round, allowing the correct position to be seleceted.

When I started to use the new camera this was also the case, but more recently, when I hit the AF point selection button, the 9 red points appear, but only for a fraction of a second, and then disapear before I can make a choice.

I've checked that my lenses (10-22, 15-85 and 70-200) are set to AF, and as far as I'm aware, haven't altered any settings in the menu that should make this change.

Also found in live view, I couldn't get focus lock (red to green) so may follow a similar theme as above?

Is the 60D set up differently, is my camera faulty, or must I go into the menu and choose an option that will return what was a very easy route used on the 500D, and also during the first few days with the 60D?

I have also found when I check past pics on the camera, some include the red focus points - which is pretty weird!

Comment: While using DPP - one of the advantages is that it does have the ability to show the focus point selected. I wouldn't call it _weird_, it can actually be quite nice to have that information.

Answer (score 6):

> When I started to use the new camera this was also the case, but more recently, when I hit the AF point selection button, the 9 red points appear, but only for a fraction of a second, and then disapear before I can make a choice.

- Select any of the *Creative Modes* (P/Tv/Av/M/B/C) on the top mode dial
- Press the *Menu* button
- Navigate to Custom Functions tab
- Navigate to *C.Fn III: Autofocus/Drive*
- Navigate to second page - *C.Fn III: Autofocus/Drive AF point selection method*
- **Make sure your value for this option is set to 0**

> I have also found when I check past pics on the camera, some include the red focus points - which is pretty weird!

- Press the *Menu* button
- Navigate to blue menu section 2
- **Make sure *"AF point disp."* is set to *Disabled***

[image]http://www.texaschicksblogsandpics.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/5d-AF-Point-Display1.jpg

Comment: Perfect - thanks very much for posting that info. All worked prefectly so I can continue using this function per my last camera.